# How to iterate over keys and values of a map in a Go html template

Tags: go, go-html-template

I have a template in go using the `http/template` package. How do I iterate over both the keys and values in the template?

Example code :

```
template := `
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Match</h1>
      <ul>
        {{range .}}
          <li> {{.}} </li>
        {{end}}
     </ul>
 </body>
</html>`

dataMap["SOMETHING"] = 124
dataMap["Something else"] = 125
t, _ := template.Parse(template)
t.Execute(w,dataMap)
```

How do I access the key in `{{range}}` in the template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing you could try is using `range` to assign two variables - one for the key, one for the value. Per [this](https://codereview.appspot.com/5543055) change (and the [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/)), the keys are returned in sorted order where possible. Here is an example using your data:

```
package main

import (
        "html/template"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        // Here we basically 'unpack' the map into a key and a value
        tem := `
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Match</h1>
      <ul>
        {{range $k, $v := . }}
          <li> {{$k}} : {{$v}} </li>
        {{end}}
     </ul>
 </body>
</html>`

        // Create the map and add some data
        dataMap := make(map[string]int)
        dataMap["something"] = 124
        dataMap["Something else"] = 125

        // Create the new template, parse and add the map
        t := template.New("My Template")
        t, _ = t.Parse(tem)
        t.Execute(os.Stdout, dataMap)
}
```

There are likely better ways of handling it, but this has worked in my (very simple) use cases :)